# AJAX append content via link on existing page

Tags: ajax

I am trying to recreate the functionality of the ajax_link example in the [Examples for Developers](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module.  Here is the code I have so far:

In animal_licence.module:

```
function animal_licence_menu() {
  $items['buy-animal-licence/animal'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'ajax_link_response',
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'file' => 'animal_licence.inc',
  );
  return $items;
}
```

In animal_licence.inc

```
function ajax_link_response($type = 'ajax') {
      if ($type == 'ajax') {
        $output = t("This is some content delivered via AJAX");
        $commands = array();
        $commands[] = ajax_command_append('#content', $output);
        $page = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
        ajax_deliver($page);
      }
      else {
        $output = t("This is some content delivered via a page load.");
        return $output;
      }
    }
```

The ajax link on-page is:

```
<a href="/buy-animal-licence/animal/nojs/" class="use-ajax ajax-processed">Click here</a>
```

When I visit /buy-animal-licence/animal/ and click the link I get the ajax spinner and it eventually times out with the following:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /buy-animal-licence/animal/ajax/
StatusText: OK
ResponseText:...
```

I'm not sure where to go from here, any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Your hook_menu implementation is missing `return $items;` - add that line at the end, clear Drupal's cache, and try the link again

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Unfortunately I truncated the code to make it more legible (there are other items within the same hook_menu function) and accidentally omitted the return.  I'll edit the question to include it but unfortunately this is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the nojs uri part in your menu item like:

```
$items['buy-animal-licence/animal/%ctools_js']
```

also, to make all more clear - your *type* argument in the callback should default to NULL

```
function ajax_link_response($type = NULL) {
```